# complex template parameter type for C++ STL set

Tags: c++, stl, set

I'm implementing an STL set with a complex template parameter type.  When inserting in to the set, I want the set to use the less-than operator I've defined for my type.  I **also** want to minimize the quantity of object instantiations of my type.  It seems I can't have both.

I've got two minimal examples below, each uses the same C++ class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
    public:
        Foo(int z);
        Foo(const Foo &z);
        bool operator<(const Foo &rhs) const;
        int a;
};

Foo::Foo(int z)
{
    cout << "cons" << endl;
    a = z;
}

Foo::Foo(const Foo &z)
{
    cout << "copy cons" << endl;
    a = z.a;
}

bool
Foo::operator<(const Foo &rhs) const
{
    cout << "less than" << endl;
    return a < rhs.a;
}
```

Here's my first main():

```
int
main(void)
{
    set<Foo> s;

    s.insert(*new Foo(1));
    s.insert(*new Foo(2));
    s.insert(*new Foo(1));

    cout << "size: " << s.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

That's great because it uses the less-than I've defined for my class, and thus the size of the set is correctly two.  But it's bad because every insertion in to the set requires the instantiation of two objects (constructor, copy constructor).

```
$ ./a.out
cons
copy cons
cons
less than
less than
less than
copy cons
cons
less than
less than
less than
size: 2
```

Here's my second main():

```
int
main(void)
{
    set<Foo *> s;

    s.insert(new Foo(1));
    s.insert(new Foo(2));
    s.insert(new Foo(1));

    cout << "size: " << s.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

That's great because an insertion requires just one object instantiation.  But it's bad because it's really a set of pointers, and thus the uniqueness of set members is gone as far as my type is concerned.

```
$ ./a.out
cons
cons
cons
size: 3
```

I'm hoping there's some bit of information I'm missing.  Is it possible for me to have both minimal object instantiations and appropriate sorting?

Comment: Why do you think a copy constructor is expensive and using operator `new` is not?

Comment: Expensive?  I don't understand your question (maybe you don't understand mine).  My issue is with **both** a copy constructor and constructor (two objects) being called for every insertion.  I don't care which is more expensive.  The sum of the two is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I would try to avoid using `new`, because I know **that** is expensive. Probably more expensive than an extra constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a copy from this: `*new Foo(1)`.

Create this struct:

```
template<typename T>
struct PtrLess
{
    bool operator()(const T *a, const T *b) const
    {
        return *a < *b;
    }
};
```

Make the map look like `set<Foo*, PtrLess<Foo>> s;` and then add Foo's like `s.insert(new Foo(1));`
Note the ***

Otherwise, when the map creates a container for the Foo item, since it is allocated within the foo containers definition, the map has to copy the supplied value into its internal Foo object.

Comment: Mranz, I think you didn't read the entire question.  Your suggestion won't work because you lose sorting.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot one part to it. I revised my answer.

Comment: @Mranz This solves the comparison problem when inserting `Foo*`, but what about the memory leak problem?

Comment: As Mranz mentions below, I will delete the objects as necessary before the set goes out of scope.  No memory leak.

Comment: There is no inherent memory leak with the proposed solution assuming somewhere down the line before the set leaves scope, you iterate over the set and delete.

Comment: @Syrinx You could delete them, or it'd be so much easier to stick the allocated `Foo` objects into a smart pointer.

Comment: Smart pointers are great, unless you are trying to shave memory requirements, or don't want to deal with the synch/copies (boost::shared_ptr does a lock around the inc/dec). It all depends on what is trying to be accomplished. At low level engine code, smart pointers can be a performance impact, however in high level code it can be a HUGE time saver.

Answer (score 1):

Standard containers store a copy of the items that are added. If you want your `set` to store objects, rather than pointers you should simply do the following, otherwise you're creating a memory leak, since the objects allocated via `new` are never free'd via a corresponding `delete`.

```
int main()
{
    set<Foo> s;

    s.insert(Foo(1));
    s.insert(Foo(2));
    s.insert(Foo(1));

    cout << "size: " << s.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If you want to minimise the number of temporary objects instantiated, just use a single temporary:

```
int main()
{
    set<Foo> s;

    Foo temp(1);
    s.insert(temp);
    temp.a = 2;
    s.insert(temp);
    temp.a = 1;
    s.insert(temp);

    cout << "size: " << s.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The output for this snippet (via `ideone`) is:

```
cons
copy cons 
less than
less than
less than
copy cons
less than
less than
less than
size: 2
```

Generally, I would prefer to store the actual objects in a `set<Foo>` rather than pointers to objects in a `set<Foo*>`, since there can be no problems with object ownership (who/when `new` and `delete` need to be called), the total amount of memory allocated is smaller (for `N` items you need `N*sizeof(Foo)` rather than `N*(sizeof(Foo) + sizeof(Foo*))` bytes) and data access *could* typically be expected to be faster (since there's no extra pointer indirection).

Hope this helps.

Comment: It would only be a memory leak if the pointers were not deleted by the time the set leaves scope. I would assume this is a contrived example since most real programs don't contain a *Foo* class.

Comment: @Mranz: I'm talking about the first example where the set is `std::set<Foo>`. In this case the temporary objects are created via `*new Foo(1) etc`, which is `allocating/constructing` new objects on the heap but never storing pointers to these objects. There is then no way to call `delete` to `destruct/free` them. This is a memory leak...

Comment: Ah yes, you are completely correct. I forgot about that part :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an extension to @Mranz's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212790/complex-template-parameter-type-for-c-stl-set/7212812#7212812). Instead of dealing with raw pointers, put the pointers in an `std::unique_ptr`

```
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct PtrLess
{
    bool operator()(const T& a, const T& b) const
    {
        return *a < *b;
    }
};


int
main(void)
{
    set<unique_ptr<Foo>, PtrLess<unique_ptr<Foo>>> s;

    s.insert(unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(1)));
    s.insert(unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(2)));
    s.insert(unique_ptr<Foo>(new Foo(1)));

    cout << "size: " << s.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```